# How can I choose the highest number in a row, and multiply it automatically with a value in the same column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in excel that can be seen below.

I want to choose the highest number in the "RPD" row and multiply it with the values that are in the same column.

So in this case the formula would take July column and multiply all the values there.

The problem is that I want to do this automatically, so when the order of values in "RPD" row changes the calculation changes automatically, still chooses the highest value in "RPD" row and multiplies it with all the values in the same column.

I also want to do this for the second highest value and so on...

So I would end up with a new row where the first column has the values for july multiplied and so on.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the `=LARGE(matrix, k)` function; where matrix will be the RPD numbers and K-esim largest number. And fix the range of your matrix.

Change MAIOIR to LARGE (i'm using it in pt_BR).

For the 1st one, the formula will be:

```
=LARGE(C5:N5; B9)*C4*C6
```

Then will have to lock the parameters by using `$`

```
=LARGE($C$5:$N$5; $B9)*C$4*C$6
```

**Output:**

[image]